# SQL query not achieveing conditionals

Tags: mysql, sql

I am meant to display the name, population, continent, independence year and life expectancy in the countries query, where the Independence year is NULL, or the country is neither in Asia nor in Europe. It shows most of the countries but the ones that achieve the conditionals of being null and being in Asia or Europe are not shown.

```
SELECT Name, Population, Continent, IndepYear, LifeExpectancy 
FROM country 
WHERE  IndepYear = NULL OR Continent != "Asia" AND Continent != "Europe";
```

Comment: The main reason for invalid result is the syntax of condition  `IndepYear = NULL` which should be written `IndepYear IS NULL`, because in case of IndepYear beeing NULL `IndepYear = NULL` will also be NULL and after that whole test will be NULL also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need:

```
SELECT Name, Population, Continent, IndepYear, LifeExpectancy 
FROM country 
WHERE  IndepYear IS NULL OR Continent NOT IN ('Asia', 'Europe');
```